# Thunderbird layout dangerously hides potential recipients of a "Reply All" response

Tags: thunderbird

When we chose REPLY ALL for an email that has multiple recipients, Thunderbird only displays the first four addresses, which may result in the email going out to unintended recipients if the sender does not notice nor take the initiative to drag down the divider or slide the scroll bar on the right side to see the other 'hidden' recipients.

Having made the unfortunate mistake of sending that was intended for SOME but not ALL of the recipients, an add-on that enables the user to set the divider that separates the email msg window from the address fields above, to expand and show ALL potential recipient addresses, when the REPLY ALL option is select would be very much appreciated.

The user can of course still drag the divider up once they've verified the recipient list.

Answer (score 1):

[Submit a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) to Mozilla.